# exporting QMultiMap<QString, QString> to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qmultimap

I have following `QObject`:

```
#ifndef UETYPES
#define UETYPES

#include <QHash>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QMultiMap>
#include <QString>
#include <QObject>

#include "../database/ueuserrecord.h"
#include "../database/ueorderrecord.h"

class UeTypes : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    typedef QHash<int, QByteArray> UeTypeRoles;

    /*
     * QString  first parameter     userId
     * QString  second parameter    placeId
     */
    typedef QMultiMap<QString, QString> UeTypeLoggedUsers;
};

#endif // UETYPES
```

and I am trying to expose/export `typedef QMultiMap<QString, QString> UeTypeLoggedUsers` to QML via `qmlRegisterType` in **main.cpp**:

```
#include <QtQml>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include "core/uetypes.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    qmlRegisterType<UeTypes::UeTypeLoggedUsers>("si.test",
                                                1,
                                                0,
                                                "UeTypeLoggedUsers");

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

However, when I try to compile this code, I get following error(s):

> error: 'staticMetaObject' is not a member of 'QMultiMap'

Why am I getting this error and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: You can expose from C++ to QML only types derived from QObject.

Comment: Btw, try QVariantMap instead. you can pass it to QML without registering.

Comment: @folibis hmm, but I need `QMultiMap`, not `QMap`, because of possibility of multiple same keys ...

Comment: Ok, but you need somehow wrap in to QObject descendant

Comment: Could you convert it to a QVariantList with pairs of key / value, instead of a QMultiMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [QVariantMap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#QVariantMap-typedef) directly in `QML` through [Qt property system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html). It is declared as `typedef QMap<QString, QVariant>`.

```
class UeTypes : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariantMap map READ map WRITE setMap NOTIFY mapChanged)

public:
    QVariantMap map() const { return mMap; }
    void setMap(QVariantMap map) {
       if(mMap != map) {
           mMap = map;
           emit mapChanged();
       }
    }

signals:
    void mapChanged();

private:
    QVariantMap mMap;

};
```

You can insert **multiple identical keys** to QMap with [QMap::insertMulti](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#insertMulti). It's equivalent to [QMultiMap::insert](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmultimap.html#insert).